# Avoid the error -- Subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I will be using the below SQL for one of the list of values.
I have data like below and I want the data to be displayed differently based on the country selection.

```
country     state
 USA        MAINE
 USA        VIRGINIA
CANADA      ALBERTA

CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  COUNTRY  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  STATE    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
)


Insert into  TEST
   (COUNTRY, STATE)
 Values
   ('USA', 'MAINE');
Insert into  TEST
   (COUNTRY, STATE)
 Values
   ('USA', 'VIRGINIA');
Insert into  TEST
   (COUNTRY, STATE)
 Values
   ('CANADA', 'ALBERTA');
COMMIT;
```

The condition is that if a country has one state then the state has be displayed by default. If the country has 2 or more states, then the user be given the option of 'Choose Your state' in the first 
row and then display the state names.
For example if the user selects 'CANADA' then 'Alberta' should be displayed by default. If the user selects 'USA', then the output should be like

1. Choose Your Stae
2. Maine
3. Virginia

I have tried to use case statement as below, but I get the error 'sub query returns more than one row' as my sub query returns multiple rows.

```
SELECT COUNTRY,
         CASE
            WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT STATE) > 1
            THEN
               (SELECT STATE
                  FROM (SELECT 'Choose One' AS STATE, 1 FROM DUAL
                        UNION
                        SELECT STATE AS STATE, 2
                          FROM TEST
                         WHERE COUNTRY IN '&COUNTRY'
                        ORDER BY 2, 1))
            WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT STATE) = 1
            THEN
               (SELECT STATE
                  FROM TEST
                 WHERE COUNTRY IN '&COUNTRY')
         END
            AS STATE
    FROM TEST
   WHERE COUNTRY IN '&COUNTRY'
GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

Please let me know how I can achieve my condition.

Thanks

Comment: How is the user going to interact with your system?

Comment: User access the system thru a BI tool

Comment: Are you sure the BI tool doesn't have the "Choose One" functionality already built in?

Comment: As the state gets populated based on the Country by default, it has restrictions being not able to give the option 'Choose to'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would invert your logic.  Not sure of Oracle syntax, so please treat this as pseudo-code:

```
SELECT 'Choose One' AS STATE, 1 WHERE (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT STATE) FROM TEST  WHERE COUNTRY IN '&COUNTRY') > 1
UNION
SELECT STATE AS STATE, 2
FROM TEST
WHERE COUNTRY IN '&COUNTRY'
ORDER BY 2, 1
```

Comment: please, fix your post, it has syntactic errors. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am a MS SQL Developer and am guessing at the Oracle syntax based on the OP.

Comment: For Oracle below worked fine         SELECT 'Choose One' AS STATE, 1 from dual WHERE (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT STATE) FROM TEST  WHERE COUNTRY IN '&COUNTRY') > 1
UNION
SELECT STATE AS STATE, 2
FROM TEST
WHERE COUNTRY IN '&COUNTRY'
ORDER BY 2, 1